# What is a better way to retrieve this XElement when reading a csproj with XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml, xelement, csproj

I'm adding files to the a cs project outside of vs.net (images, css, etc, files outside our group but are necessary to Publish). I'm loading the csproj and querying for the ItemGroup that contains the "Content" nodes.

```
XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
XDocument projectDocument = XDocument.Load("someproject.csproj");

var itemGroup = projectDocument.Element(msbuild + "Project")
                               .Elements(msbuild + "ItemGroup")
                               .Descendants()
                               .Where(x => x.Name == msbuild +"Content")
                               .First().Parent;
```

Is there a better way to get this group?

Thank you.

Comment: Nothings wrong, i was wondering if there was a more direct call that could be made

Comment: Looks like my comment didn't apply.  The only thing I can see is that you could get an exception if there are no matching elements to portions of your LINQ statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var itemGroup = 
    projectDocument.Element(msbuild + "Project")
                   .Elements(msbuild + "ItemGroup")
                   .Where(x => x.Descendants()
                                .Any(y => y.Name == msbuild +"Content")
                         )
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```